# On-demand video streaming with single format on server

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront, flash-media-server

I am developing a web app that streams videos (pre-recorded, not live) on demand. I stored my videos (mp4 files) in Amazon S3 bucket. My application is running on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI). The web app uses JW Player to display the videos. I was able to get the application up and running. As the next step, I am planning to move to a solution based on CloudFront and Adobe Flash Media Server (FMS) to achieve true streaming video rather that the progressive download solution I have in place now. Before that, I have a couple of questions nagging me.

The issue I had with my current setup was that my videos played fine in Safari, IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox. I understand that it is because Firefox doesn't support mp4 format. I do not want to create 3 versions of the same video (mp4, webm and ogg) so the player can fallback to the version supported by the browser.

1. Is there a way to have one version of the video file (say, mp4) on the server and dynamically stream in the format supported by the client browser/device (for e.g. stream in ogg format to FF browser and in mp4 to Safari/Chrome)?
2. Does FMS provide the ability to do so?

Answer (score 0):

1. FF does not support H.264 in HTML5 tag, you can use http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody. Which will fall back to flash plugin if HTML5 is not supported.
2. FMS does not provide transcoding functionality, you can use "wowza" but its paid.